# How to correct encoding that went wrong

Tags: unicode, utf-8, vbscript, character-encoding, adodb

I have a VBscript code that processes utf-8 files.

It works perfectly. Except there is a problem with the source files in that sometimes the input (despite the script is clearly labeled to be used for utf-8 files) is unicode-LE.

This then creates a corrupt output of course. I am putting in a check for the BOM to ensure no Unicode-LE files are opened incorrectly. But I already have files that got corrupted this way.

Is there a way to seamlessly revert the damage? Meaning to read it back "incorrectly" and saving it correctly?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UnicodeToUTF8(ByVal InFName, ByVal OutFName)
    Dim strText

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .LoadFromFile InFName
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        'Read Unicode source file
        strText = .ReadText(adReadAll)
        'Process file
        strText = OffsetTCs(strText)
        'Output UTF-8 file
        .Position = 0
        .SetEOS
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .WriteText strText, adWriteChar
        .SaveToFile OutFName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
I tried this script to save the day, but it reports an error on the `file.Write data` line. It does show the ASCII content properly in the message box, but not the Chinese characters:

```
Dim fso, file, data
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("damaged_Test.sub", 1, False, -1)
data = ""
data = file.ReadAll
MsgBox(data)
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True)
file.Write data
```

Here is the hex dump of the damaged file:

```
EF BB BF EF BF BD EF BF BD 5B 00 53 00 63 00 72 00 69 00 70 00 74 00 20 00 49 00 6E 00 66 00 6F 00 5D 00 0D 00 0A 00 3B 00 0D 00 0A 00 54 00 69 00 74 00 6C 00 65 00 3A 00 20 00 20 00 28 00 29 00 0D 00 0A 00 4F 00 72 00 69 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 61 00 6C 00 20 00 53 00 63 00 72 00 69 00 70 00 74 00 3A 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 4F 00 72 00 69 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 61 00 6C 00 20 00 54 00 69 00 6D 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 3A 00 20 00 0D 00 0A 00 53 00 63 00 72 00 69 00 70 00 74 00 54 00 79 00 70 00 65 00 3A 00 20 00 76 00 34 00 2E 00 30 00 38 00 0D 00 0A 00 43 00 6F 00 6C 00 6C 00 69 00 73 00 69 00 6F 00 6E 00 73 00 3A 00 20 00 4E 00 6F 00 72 00 6D 00 61 00 6C 00 0D 00 0A 00 50 00 6C 00 61 00 79 00 52 00 65 00 73 00 58 00 3A 00 20 00 31 00 32 00 38 00 30 00 0D 00 0A 00 50 00 6C 00 61 00 79 00 52 00 65 00 73 00 59 00 3A 00 20 00 37 00 32 00 30 00 0D 00 0A 00 50 00 6C 00 61 00 79 00 44 00 65 00 70 00 74 00 68 00 3A 00 20 00 30 00 0D 00 0A 00 54 00 69 00 6D 00 65 00 72 00 3A 00 20 00 31 00 30 00 30 00 2E 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00 5B 00 56 00 34 00 20 00 53 00 74 00 79 00 6C 00 65 00 73 00 5D 00 0D 00 0A 00 46 00 6F 00 72 00 6D 00 61 00 74 00 3A 00 20 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 46 00 6F 00 6E 00 74 00 6E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 46 00 6F 00 6E 00 74 00 73 00 69 00 7A 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 50 00 72 00 69 00 6D 00 61 00 72 00 79 00 43 00 6F 00 6C 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 2C 00 20 00 53 00 65 00 63 00 6F 00 6E 00 64 00 61 00 72 00 79 00 43 00 6F 00 6C 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 2C 00 20 00 54 00 65 00 72 00 74 00 69 00 61 00 72 00 79 00 43 00 6F 00 6C 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 2C 00 20 00 42 00 61 00 63 00 6B 00 43 00 6F 00 6C 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 2C 00 20 00 42 00 6F 00 6C 00 64 00 2C 00 20 00 49 00 74 00 61 00 6C 00 69 00 63 00 2C 00 20 00 42 00 6F 00 72 00 64 00 65 00 72 00 53 00 74 00 79 00 6C 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 4F 00 75 00 74 00 6C 00 69 00 6E 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 53 00 68 00 61 00 64 00 6F 00 77 00 2C 00 20 00 41 00 6C 00 69 00 67 00 6E 00 6D 00 65 00 6E 00 74 00 2C 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 4C 00 2C 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 52 00 2C 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 56 00 2C 00 20 00 41 00 6C 00 70 00 68 00 61 00 4C 00 65 00 76 00 65 00 6C 00 2C 00 20 00 45 00 6E 00 63 00 6F 00 64 00 69 00 6E 00 67 00 0D 00 0A 00 53 00 74 00 79 00 6C 00 65 00 3A 00 20 00 50 00 75 00 62 00 6C 00 69 00 63 00 2C 00 44 00 46 00 4B 00 61 00 69 00 53 00 68 00 75 00 20 00 53 00 74 00 64 00 20 00 57 00 35 00 2C 00 35 00 32 00 2C 00 31 00 32 00 35 00 37 00 31 00 38 00 37 00 32 00 2C 00 31 00 32 00 35 00 37 00 31 00 38 00 37 00 32 00 2C 00 31 00 32 00 35 00 37 00 31 00 38 00 37 00 32 00 2C 00 2D 00 32 00 31 00 34 00 37 00 34 00 38 00 33 00 36 00 34 00 30 00 2C 00 2D 00 31 00 2C 00 30 00 2C 00 31 00 2C 00 33 00 2C 00 33 00 2C 00 32 00 2C 00 31 00 32 00 38 00 2C 00 31 00 32 00 38 00 2C 00 37 00 32 00 2C 00 30 00 2C 00 31 00 33 00 36 00 0D 00 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00 5B 00 45 00 76 00 65 00 6E 00 74 00 73 00 5D 00 0D 00 0A 00 46 00 6F 00 72 00 6D 00 61 00 74 00 3A 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 6B 00 65 00 64 00 2C 00 20 00 53 00 74 00 61 00 72 00 74 00 2C 00 20 00 45 00 6E 00 64 00 2C 00 20 00 53 00 74 00 79 00 6C 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 2C 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 4C 00 2C 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 52 00 2C 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 67 00 69 00 6E 00 56 00 2C 00 20 00 45 00 66 00 66 00 65 00 63 00 74 00 2C 00 20 00 54 00 65 00 78 00 74 00 0D 00 0A 00 44 00 69 00 61 00 6C 00 6F 00 67 00 75 00 65 00 3A 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 6B 00 65 00 64 00 3D 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 38 00 2E 00 36 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 3A 00 31 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 30 00 2C 00 50 00 75 00 62 00 6C 00 69 00 63 00 2C 00 30 00 31 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 2C 00 EF BF BD 65 74 5E EF BF BD 5F 02 6A 0D 00 0A 00 44 00 69 00 61 00 6C 00 6F 00 67 00 75 00 65 00 3A 00 20 00 4D 00 61 00 72 00 6B 00 65 00 64 00 3D 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 3A 00 31 00 31 00 2E 00 32 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 3A 00 31 00 35 00 2E 00 31 00 33 00 2C 00 50 00 75 00 62 00 6C 00 69 00 63 00 2C 00 30 00 31 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 2C 00 2C 00 EF BF BD 65 74 5E EF BF BD 5F 02 6A 0D 00 0A
```

Comment: Why are you reading it in a binary?

Comment: @Noodles A utf-8 text file with text in it. And some of the files are incorrectly saved as unicode-LE.

Comment: Why are you reading it as binary?

Comment: @Noodles To ensure that all language's all characters are read correctly. It is based on some code on SO.

Comment: If you already know that some of the input files can be UTF-16LE encoded, then why don't you simply detect that and re-read them as UTF-16LE, rather than, as you seem to want, running the whole routine and then run another routine to undo the damage caused?

Comment: Please check the corrupt files with a hex editor (e.g. HxD) to verify if only the BOM was changed or if there were further damage as well. In case of the former simply changing the BOM back should suffice.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, of course, that is what I meant. But I already have damaged files, as an unexpected outcome. The script was intended to be used only for utf-8 files. So that is not the question. How to undo the damage is the question.

Comment: Try `Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") : fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True).Write fso.OpenTextFile("input.txt", 1, False, -1).ReadAll` where "input.txt" is one of your damaged files. Make sure you write the output to a different file. Is the output still damaged? If so: how exactly? Please [edit] your question and show a hexdump of the first couple lines.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers See update on OP. I tried your suggestion, but it would not write the file. The display in the `MsgBox` does show ansii characters correctly, but the Unicode ones are corrupted, as well as the BOM.

Comment: Hmm... I'd probably start by creating a copy of the corrupted file, replace the the UTF-8 BOM (`EF BB BF`) and the subsequent double `EF BF BD` in that copy with a UTF-16LE BOM (`FF FE`), and retry the procedure I suggested above. See how far that gets you. There appear to be a couple non-ascii byte sequences in the dump, though. Not sure what to make of them.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `B0 65 74 5E EB 5F 02 6A` (Happy new year in Chinese) is what is in the original Unicode-LE twice at the end of both lines. This got corrupted to what you see above (`EF BF BD 65 74 5E EF BF BD 5F 02 6A`). With deleting everything up to the `5B` and adding the `FF FE` gives me the error "Invalid procedure call or argument" so I can't save the file out.